# My bluetooth app stps working unexpetedly....It's a fairly small program

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with my bluetooth app unexpectedly closing....

The code can succesfully do the following....

(1) Get the bluetooth adapter
(2) Enable the bluetooth adapter

The problem seems to occur when trying to query paired devices....

The problem seems to be at the end of the code where this code block occurs....

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();  
// If there are paired devices
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {        
// Loop through paired devices    
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {       
        // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
        mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());    
    }
}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();  
// If there are paired devices
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {        
// Loop through paired devices    
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {       
        // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
        mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());    
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I format my code into blocks instead of inline code?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the code from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html).

Do you have an activity in your application which has a list view and the mArrayAdapter is not null ?
It may be worth testing by writing the information using the logger function `Log.i()` or just to `System.out` just to make sure you are getting the expected output.

Failing that, it could be that there is no bluetooth device present, or the mBluetoothAdapter is null or it is not enabled causing the application to force close.

EDIT: Comments section is horrible to try and format code. Have you tried something like this?

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {    
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {     
        Log.i("BluetoothApp", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    }
}
```

The data should appear in the LogCat section of Eclipse.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your reply...I'm new to java and OOP, most of my experince is just plain C, so I'm not real knowledgable, but here is the answer to your questions (1) So far the mArrayAdapter part of the code is the most shrouded in mystery to me. (2) There is bluetooth present, The google bluetooth chat app works on the phone just not my code...............

Comment: The ArrayAdapter is a way of binding collections of objects on to a visual component, in this case a list view. That documentation kind-of skims over that.

Comment: Is the Log.i() method that you speak of, related to some kind of file that is generated when you run the emulator? The reason I ask is because I'm not using the emulator, I'm actually putting it on my phone and running it....

Comment: No, it is an Android utility that allows you to output information that can be helpful during debugging: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: So, if I use the log() method, create the apk file and run it on my phone, where does the information go? Where or what is the name of the file the log() function outputs info to? I'm actually running through the android development website, but it's never as efficient as a real human, Thanks man...

Comment: The Log is just a real time trace of these messages from various applications and the Android system. It is just to test that you can access the Bluetooth hardware.
If you connect your phone in debug mode via USB, you can debug whilst on your phone and view these messages. They wont be visible from the handset itself. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: Thanks again, I'm still going throught the information in the link you provided, I have also hooked up the phone to usb, and placed the phone in debug mode and then run the known good code, but it does'nt seem to be running on the phone. I have used both the run and debug options? Do you (1) run the code from eclipse using run or debug? or (2) Run the apk file on your phone? Any links on how this works would be equally appreciated.

Comment: No worries. Basically, the application needs to be set into debug mode using the manifest. You click "debug as" then Android application, it should then start the main activity. I would suggest working through these exercises, it should help in terms of writing and debugging Android applications:  http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html